# ALTER command takes too much time in AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have one instance of Postgresql running as AWS RDS instance.

I logged in as admin user in the terminal and tried to add a column to a table whose owner is admin.

The table only has 23 rows. It's a dev machine. So, no connections to it apart from mine. It takes forever to respond. I do not know what is going on.

Comment: Probably some other connection still keeping locks on the table in question. See: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring for some queries you can use

Comment: I ran the query under "Сombination of blocked and blocking activity" and it gave me 0 results. Plus, I will eventually need to run this query in prod DB. So, it will have connections.

Comment: There are some idle queries that ran in September. Killed them using pg_terminate_backend(pid) and then it worked. Thank you.